# Will Roalesk, Apex Hybrid, trigger Sharktocrab twice?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Sharktocrab](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSharktocrab%5d) reads

> Whenever one or more +1/+1 counters are put on Sharktocrab, tap target creature an opponent controls. That creature doesn't untap during its controller's next untap step.

If I were to put two +1/+1 counters on it *at once*, by playing [Vivien of the Arkbow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVivien%20of%20the%20Arkbow%5d), then its ability would only trigger once.

But what about [Roalesk, Apex Hybrid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRoalesk%2c%20Apex%20Hybrid%5d), which reads

> When Roalesk dies, proliferate, then proliferate again.

The first ability is placing a counter on Sharktocrab, just like when I use Vivien. But the Roalesk then places *another* counter separately. Would Sharktocrab therefore trigger twice?

Comment: Count the instructions (verbs). Everything an instruction has you do is done simultaneously, but each instruction is performed in turn.

Comment: @ikegami though there are exceptions, like drawing multiple cards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it would.

Even though no one gets priority in between the instructions "proliferate" and "then proliferate again"; each instruction is still a separate instance, and Sharktocrab's ability will trigger after each of them.

Abilities trigger as soon as the relevant event happens; they don't wait to trigger until an entire ability is done resolving.

> 603.2. Whenever a game event or game state matches a triggered ability’s trigger event, that ability automatically triggers. The ability doesn’t do anything at this point.
>
> 603.3. Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card the next time a player would receive priority.